# How to fix the "ID3035: The request was not valid or is malformed." error when uploading a file to a SharePoint document library using PHP and OAuth2?

Tags: php, curl, sharepoint, file-upload, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to upload a file to a SharePoint document library using PHP and OAuth2 authentication. However, I'm getting an "ID3035: The request was not valid or is malformed." error. Here's my code:

```
// URL of the SharePoint site
$site_url = 'https://usbbogedu.sharepoint.com/vacademica';

// Name of the document library where you want to upload the file
$library_name = 'Plan de Trabajo';

// Name of the file you want to upload
$file_name = 'mi-archivo.pdf';

// Full path of the file on your local system
$file_path = '../subida_sp/Azul.jpg';

// OAuth2 authentication information
$client_id = 'client_id ';
$client_secret = 'client_secret ';
$tenant_id = 'tenant_id';
$resource = 'https://usbbogedu.sharepoint.com';

// Get OAuth2 access token
$auth_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant_id/oauth2/token";
$ch = curl_init($auth_url);
$data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    'resource' => $resource
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (false == $response) {
    echo "Error getting OAuth2 access token\n";
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
$token = json_decode($response)->access_token;

// SharePoint API URL
$url = $site_url . "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('$library_name')/RootFolder/Files/add(url='$file_name',overwrite=true)";

// File content
$file_content = file_get_contents($file_path);

// Authentication headers with OAuth2
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($file_content)
);

// HTTP POST request
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (false == $response) {
    echo "Request failed\n";
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    foreach($info as $ent){
        echo $ent . "<br>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Response ". $response ."\n";
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($response);
}
```

I have tried to upload a file to SharePoint using the provided code and have received the error message 'Respuesta {"error_description":"ID3035: The request was not valid or is malformed."}'. I have checked the credentials and they are correct. I was expecting the file to be uploaded successfully to the designated library in SharePoint. Can you please help me understand what could be causing this error?

Comment: Is this really supposed to work by putting a relative path into the URL directly, `add(url='$file_name',overwrite=true)` ...? Where is the documentation that you based this on?

Comment: i used chatgpt for my question and he give this information "To upload files to SharePoint with PHP without using Microsoft's Graph, you can use the SharePoint API.First, you'll need to get the URL of the SharePoint site where you want to upload the file and also the login credentials to authenticate to the site.You can then use a combination of PHP and CURL to make an HTTP POST request to the SharePoint API, providing the information needed to upload the file.Here is a basic example of how you can do it:"  y also give the code that it is in the first question?

Comment: @jaisondariobejaranovaldes any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The response means you successfully acquired an access token with the app registration details, but SharePoint rejected it because your app doesn't have access to the SharePoint API.

For the authentication component to work you need to do two things:

- The app registration needs to be granted permission to access sites: SharePoint > Application Permissions > Sites.Selected
- The app registration needs to be granted write access to the specific sharepoint site via a graph query: [see here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/develop-applications-that-use-sites-selected-permissions-for-spo/ba-p/3790476)

Next, In your POST to upload file, you also need to include a header "X-RequestDigest" with a value you can get by doing a POST to "https://{site url}/_api/contextinfo". [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints?redirectedfrom=MSDN#writing-data-by-using-the-rest-interface)